# Gatttool "Characteristic Write Request failed:" How to reduce fail timeout for read/write?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, read-write, gatt, characteristics

I'm reading and writing the characteristics from my board using bluez-4.101. using gatttool.

sometimes i get Characteristic Write Request failed: or read failed.

Frequency of these errors is like 2/10, is there something that i can do to make full proof, if it is usual, I'd like to reduce the timeout i get before failing.

Answer (score 3):

If you say the frequency is not 100% then this is probably not a software issue. Rather, you might have to bring that your devices are brought closer together so that there is less chance of interference, or that your advertising device has a higher tx power.

Unfortunately there is no option through the BlueZ commands to reduce the timeout. I'm guessing you are using the gatttool command to interrogate the gatt table on the other end. Use `#gatttool --help-all` for a full list of the options and you will see that the timeout is not one of them.

Comment: thanks Yousif for reply. 
I'm not sure if i can reduce the distance, the use case is like for about 8 9 meters.